# Using JPA entity listeners to persist JPA entities

Tags: spring, activerecord, jpa, transactions, entitylisteners

I have the following method in a JPA EntityListener:

```
@PostPersist
    void onPostPersist(Pli pli) {
        EvenementPli event = new EvenementPli();
        event.setPli(pli);
        event.setDateCreation(new Date());
        event.setDateEvenement(new Date());
        event.setType(TypeEvenement.creation);
        event.setMessage("Création d'un pli");
        event.persist();
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to create an event by persisting an instance of `EvenementPli` each time an instance of the `Pli` entity is persisted.

The trouble is that the by the time `event.persist();` is called the Pli row is not in the database which causes Mysql to complain about the constraint...

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appropriate solution is to redesign application such a way, that persisting EvenementPli happens somewhere else than in @PostPersist callback method of other entity. According JPA 2.0 specification such a operations are not guaranteed to work in lifecycle callback methods:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>   invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity
>   instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>   context.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. I was not aware of this aspect of the spec. I am going to have to come back to aspectJ...